How to implement handling of environment with flutter/supabase?
I started with flutter and chose supabase as my backend for some reasons. I can use 2 projects there. So I wanna use one for development/test and one for production later. How should I implement the flutter app in handling these environments properly?
Cheers
No idea how to implement the handling of dev and prod environment in flutter app

You can use flutter_dotenv package for handle environment flutter_dotenv
or
You can create a class which handle keys according package/build Id.
package_info_plus and rename these help you to do so.

Thank you. Should I store credentials for the DB in such .env files or better in code?
